# How to put visible JSurfaceTexture or JSurface on my FMX form?

Tags: android, delphi, camera, firemonkey

I am implementing my own camera app for Android using Delphi XE6. Recording of video files works (see my answer to [Record video from camera on Android to mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837928/record-video-from-camera-on-android-to-mp4)) however I would like to have a "viewfinder" for my camera.

`JMediaRecorder` class has method `setPreviewDisplay` which accepts `JSurface` object. How I can place this `JSurface` (or `JSurfaceTexture` as an alternative) on my form?

`JSurfaceTexture`  has method `attachToGLContext`, but it is unclear how o use it?

Comment: The DPF Android components should be able to help. http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiandroid/

Comment: DPF Android components include TJDPFVIdeoView which has GetJVideoView.getHolder methods. This works perfectly for preview, however it is not exactly native Delphi way, because you have to replace classes.dex file etc. Can it be done without such tricks?

Comment: @AlexGornostayev Were you able to solve this?