# Accessing C-Objective code from within delphi?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I was wondering if it is possible to access C-Objective code from within delphi. In a research i've done that seems to be possible but the posts i've seen they were not that detailed so i couldn't figure out how the process works. For the android platform i've found that it could be done this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/29840534 . Actually this is what i am trying to do, to run the camera of the specified platform. So any help or directions about what should i read would be more than welcome.

Comment: There are two questions in one: 1) how to use the camera using C-objective code, and 2) how to wrap this code in Delphi. For the second question, here is some general information about how it works: http://blog.blong.com/2013/05/delphi-for-ios-some-notes.html and http://ridingdelphi.blogspot.dk/2014/01/the-quest-to-migrate-ios-squarecam-app_3169.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links...I will have a look into them as soon as possible :)

Comment: Why do you want to import objective C to run the device's camera?  Why not use Delphi's built-in camera interfaces?  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Taking_Pictures_Using_FireMonkey_Interfaces

Comment: For photos i am using the Delphi's built-in functionallity but the interface doesn't support recording of a video and that is what i am looking for.

Comment: @Hans : The links seem to be what i was looking for but they are a bit more complicated than i expected to be :s

Comment: @StamatisLiatsos Yes, it looks complicated and I have mainly used them as reference. When you know the objective C code that does what you want, then it is less complicated. All (or most) objective C classes are implemented as interfaces in Delphi (same name as the objective C name), so you can simply call the same functions. I suggest that you first find the answer to question 1 (how to do it in objective C) and then, if you have problems adapting it to Delphi, ask again here on SO, with the actual code.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot :)...If you want you can post your comment as an answer to my question so i can upvote it.